# How do I write JavaFX custom property editors for custom controls

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

We have developed a number of custom JavaFX controls which we build into a JAR and then allow our clients (internal and external) to load into SceneBuilder and then create UI's with those controls. We would like to attach custom property editors to some properties on these controls.

As a made up example, say we have a GraphControl that displays line graphs. It has multiple properties, one of which is "TickStyle", an enum with options DOT, CROSS, CIRCLE, BIG_TICK_STYLE, SMALL_TICK_STYLE, etc.

Now, when I insert this control into SceneBuilder (as a JAR), I can drop instances onto the design canvas. Cool. But I don't want a boring combo-box of tick style values (the enum's toString) e.g. "BIG_TICK_STYLE", but a pretty picker with graphical representations.

The JavaBean spec has the PropertyEditor interface and the BeanInfo thing which does the same thing for Swing. Does this work for JavaFx and how? If it doesn't work for JavaFX, then is there an alternative?

We really don't want to go down the route of hacking SceneBuilder, we just don't have time or people for that.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

SceneBuilder seems to have its own complex property editors, e.g. for colours. We need editors for

1. more complex property types (to any level of complexity) such as the Insets editor
   [image: SceneBuilder insets editor]
2. more complex editors, such as the colour editor
   [image: SceneBuilder color picker]

Comment: I'm not sure Scene Builder is sophisticated enough for what you want—at least publicly.

Comment: [_Ensemble8_](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html) may be an example.